# Virtually large groups of small rank (related to 3-manifolds)

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, 3-manifolds

**Edited 25.05.21: the assumptions of the question were incorrect**, but as the discussion may be helpful for future MOnauts, I'll strike my mistakes and add clearly marked explanations afterwards.

I am looking for a reason why a 3-manifold group $G$ that is virtually $\mathbb{Z}\times F$, $F$ being <s>either non-cyclic free or</s> a surface group, does not admit a presentation on two generators.

These are the fundamental groups of closed 3-manifolds with $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ geometry (**Added:** thanks @HJRW for pointing out that the strike-through case above corresponds to a non-empty boundary), and it turns out that all other geometries admit examples with fundamental group of rank two, with notable highlight of euclidean geometry where all fundamental groups are virtually $\mathbb{Z}^3$ (and rank two example being the Hantzche–Wendt/Fibonacci manifold). Thus the 3-manifold groups admit examples of virtually high rank groups being nonetheless of small rank themselves. Of course it is well known that a free group on two generators is virtually of arbitrarily high rank.

However, by [Boileau & Zieschang](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01388469), Theorem 1.1, the rank of $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ manifolds depends on the genus of the base surface and number of singular fibers of the Seifert fibration <s>(and is at least 3)</s>, so apparently being virtually $\mathbb{Z}\times F$ forces the group to be of at least the same rank.

**Added:** this is my initial confusion - I assumed that the base orbifold of a $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ manifold must have genus at least 2, but this is not true. In fact, following the [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_fiber_space) conventions for Seifert spaces, $\{-1,(o_1,0);(5,1),(5,2),(5,2)\}$ is a $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ manifold Seifert-fibering over a shpere, which in particular fits into Theorem 1.1, case ii) of the cited paper (just don't let the initial $g>0$ mislead you) and is indeed of both rank and genus 2. I thank again @HJRW for their comments which got me on the right track eventually. This of course makes the question that followed invalid.

<s>What is the cause that this subgroup bounds the rank of the ambient group from below and, say, free groups or abelian free $\mathbb{Z}^3$ do not? I would be happy if there is a geometric 3-dimensional reason in play here, but would be grateful for refreshing my general group theory as well.</s>

Comment: Just to be sure: you mean that in the Boileau-Zieschang paper there's a claim that any finite index overgroup of such a $\mathbf{Z}\times F$ group has generating rank $\ge 3$, and you want an explanation of this claim?

Comment: Hint: Consider the exterior of the trefoil knot. Do you know a presentation of its fundamental group? Can you prove that this group is virtually $Z\times F$?

Comment: @YCor, Boileau-Zieschang show that Seifert fibered space of prescribed symbol (as per the classification by genus + Euler number + twisting of exceptional fibers) must have fundamental group of a specific rank (2 times genus + number of fibers - 1). Then, using that (by geometrization) a 3-manifold has a fundamental group virtually $\mathbb{Z}\times F$ iff it fits in one of the cases in their paper, we get that any finite index overgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\times F$ *that is a 3-manifold group* has generating rank $\geq 3$. I wasn't sure if the 3-manifoldness was necessary or if it was algebraic...

Comment: ...but by @MoisheKohan's hint (that should follow from the trefoil group being the extension of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$?) it seems that being a fundamental group of a closed 3-manifold is indeed a restriction in this case.

Comment: In the second paragraph you talk about “closed 3-manifolds”, but in the first paragraph you allow $F$ to be free, which corresponds to the case with toroidal boundary. Could you clarify which case you care about? In the closed case, a finite extension is a 3-manifold group iff it’s torsion-tree, so it is just an algebraic condition. I suspect the same is true in the case with boundary, but am less certain.

Comment: Oh, I see from the comment thread that you do want the manifold to be closed. Perhaps you should update the question?

Comment: @HJRW, corrected, thanks. Copied and pasted the condition from a book without thinking.

Comment: Could you explain how it follows from Boileau and Zieschang that the rank is at least 3 when the geometry is H^2 x R? If I remember correctly, there are Seifert fibred manifolds with Euler number zero that fibre over a hyperbolic triangle orbifold (2,3,7), say. These would have H^2 x R geometry, and Boileau and Zieschang seem to imply that their rank is 2.

Comment: @HJRW, I finally convinced myself that I understand where I went wrong, and edited the question accordingly. Though I think that (2,3,7) is not a good example, as it won't have the Euler characteristic zero - if this denotes the sphere with three singular points of the appropriate degree. Nevertheless, thank you so very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @lemon314 -- I'm so glad to been of some assistance! I'm slightly confused about your comment about the (2,3,7) orbifold; this is just the smallest hyperbolic orbifold with underlying surface the sphere, and indeed any hyperbolic orbifold will have negative (orbifold) Euler characteristic. But anyway, it doesn't matter.

Comment: to clarify - I meant the Euler number of the Seifert manifold; to have $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ geometry, the orbifold Euler characteristic must be negative, and the Euler number must be zero - and I meant that $x/2+y/3+z/7$ is not an integer for the admissible $x,y,z$, and so that second condition would fail;

Answer (score 5):

The question stems from a misinterpretation of Theorem 1.1 in the paper by Boileau  and Zieschang. Theorem 1.1 excludes a fair number of cases, in particular, it does not apply to (totally oriented) closed Seifert manifolds with 3 singular fibers and base of genus 0. Some of these excluded Seifert manifolds provide counter-examples to your claim about rank $\ge 3$.

For instance, take the exterior $N$ of a $(p,q)$-[torus knot](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6810/seifert-surfaces-of-torus-knots) which is nontrivial and not the trefoil. The genus of this knot is
$$
g=\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}\ge 2
$$
(because I excluded the trefoil which has genus 1). The manifold $N$ is a surface bundle over the circle whose fiber $F$ is the once-punctured surface of genus $g$. The monodromy of this fibration is a finite order (actually, the order is $pq$) homeomorphism $h: F\to F$. Thus, if we collapse the boundary of $F$ to point, we obtain a closed surface $S$ of genus $g$ and $h$ will project to a finite order homeomorphism $f: S\to S$. The mapping torus $M=M_f$ is a Seifert manifold of type ${\mathbb H}^2\times {\mathbb R}$ obtained by a Dehn filling of the boundary of $N$. The base of the Seifert fibration will have three singular points and genus 0: Two of the singular fibers come from $N$ and one comes from the solid torus attached to $\partial N$ as the result of our Dehn filling.
(It is a general fact that the mapping torus of a finite order homeomorphism of a hyperbolic surface is a Seifert manifold of type ${\mathbb H}^2\times {\mathbb R}$.) Since the group $\pi_1(N)$ is 2-generated, the quotient group $\pi_1(M)$ is also 2-generated.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and clarifications. You are right, somehow I convinced myself that $\mathbb{H}^2\times\mathbb{R}$ geometry forces the base orbifold to be of higher genus. I will unconvince myself now, then accept your answer and edit the question accordingly:)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking half a year later, how is $\pi_1(M)$ obviously 2-generated? Well, how is it obviously a quotient, actually - on the face of it, Mayer-Vietoris will give us three generators, two from $N$ and one from the filling - is there any obvious reason why the rank doesn't rise? Is that related to how the inclusion of the boundary in a 3-manifold obeys the "half lives half dies" rule in $H_1$?

Comment: You can think of Dehn filling as consisting of two steps.  First attach a (three-dimensional) two-handle and second attach a three-ball (a three-handle). In terms of the fundamental group, the first adds a relation and the second does nothing.  Thus Dehn filling causes a quotient in $\pi_1$.

Comment: @lemon314: I think you are quite confused, mixing up homology, fundamental group and who knows what else. The fact that you somehow came with a 3-generator set for a group (more precisely, its abelianization given by the first homology) does not imply that there is no 2-generator set. I suggest, you start by going through a proof that each torus knot group is 2-generated (meaning admits a 2-generator set).

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I did mean Seifert-van Kampen in the first sentence, I apologize for the confusion; I will head your advice, but I stand by the initial impression: since S-vK gives a presentation with +1 generators and +1 relations, that this doesn't change the rank of the group will need a reason that will probably be related to how the inclusion of a boundary is somewhat constrained algebraically

Comment: @lemon314: There is more than one way to compute $\pi_1$ of the Dehn filling in this situation. If you do this naively, then, indeed, you get an extra generator. But, as Sam Need says, if you do the computation in two steps then you only add an extra relator and no extra generators. I do not understand the meaning of  "will probably be related to how the inclusion of a boundary is somewhat constrained algebraically."